# reading text file and assigning strings from file to variables

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a few problems with my code. I want to be able to read input from a text file and take the strings from each line or between spaces and assign them to variables that I will pass to an object.

My first problem is that my program misreads one of my lines and omits the first letter from a variable, and the second problem is I don't know how to make my program read two strings on the same line and assign them to different variables.

```
    System.out.println("Input the file name of the text file you want to open:(remember .txt)");
    keyboard.nextLine();
    String filename=keyboard.nextLine();

    FileReader freader=new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader inputFile=new BufferedReader(freader);

    courseName=inputFile.readLine();

    while (inputFile.read()!= -1) {
        fName=inputFile.readLine(); 
        lName=inputFile.readLine();
        officeNumber=inputFile.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println(fName);
    Instructor inst=new Instructor(fName,lName,officeNumber);
    System.out.println(inst);
    inputFile.close();

}
```

I am not very good at using filereader and have tried to use the scanner keyboard method, but it lead me to even more errors :(

Output:
Input from a file (F) or keyboard (K): 
F
Input the file name of the text file you want to open: (remember .txt)
test.txt
un bun
un bun won won's office number is null

text file:
professor messor
bun bun
won won

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read one line with `readLine()` then you say that you want to split with `whitespace`.

So you have to do something like this

```
    String line=null;
    List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = inputFile.readLine())!= null) {
            String[] arrayLine= line.split("\\s+"); // here you are splitting with whitespace 
            courseName = arrayLine[0]
            lName=arrayLine[1];
            officeNumber=arrayLine[2];
            list.add(new Course(courseName,lName,officeNumber));   
          // you sure want do something with this create an object for example

        }

 // in some part br.close();
```

Here you have an example [How to read a File](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `read()` in the condition of the `while` loop, the "cursor" of the BufferedReader advances one character. You don't want to do this to check if the stream can be read, you want to use the `ready()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution using StringTokenizer

```
    String line=null;
    List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((line = inputFile.readLine())!= null) {
       StringTokenizer sToken = new StringTokenizer(input, " ");
       list.add(new Course(sToken.nextToken(),sToken.nextToken(),sToken.nextToken())); 
    }
```